# How does elf-loader knows the address of stderr and stdout

Tags: linux, elf, dynamic-loading

I am disassembling a very simple ELF program (Linux x86).
With IDA PRO software I see `stdout` and `stderr` in `.bss`-section. 
And I haven't found anything that sets the values of `stdout` or `stderr`. 
How does it work?
Сan `stdout` and `stderr` be null?

Comment: stdout and stderr are file handles created by the c runtime. Your program expects the system to have already created them. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html

Comment: So you mean stdout and stderr should always be at the same memory address in .bss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you mean stdout and stderr should always be at the same memory address in .bss

The offset from start of `.bss` to `stdout` and `stderr` is determined at static link time.

The address of start of `.bss` is subject to ASLR (heap placement randomization). Thus, for a given binary, the address of `stdout` may change from run to run.

> how IDA pro knows this item in .bss is stdout or stderr

The only way it *can* know is via the symbol table. You should see it in output from:

```
readelf -Ws ./a.out | egrep 'stdout|stderr'
nm ./a.out          | egrep 'stdout|stderr'
nm -D ./a.out       | egrep 'stdout|stderr'
```

**Update:**

> but what happens if symbol table is stripped

There are two cases to consider: fully-static link, and dynamic link.

In the fully-static case, all references to `stderr` can be completely removed, and IDA pro will *not* know where `stderr` is.

In the dynamically-linked case, there are two symbol tables: the "regular" one (displayed by `nm`) and the dynamic one (displayed by `nm -D`). Strip will remove *only* the regular symbol table (because removing dynamic symbol table makes no sense -- the executable will not run without it). IDA pro can then use the dynamic symbol table entry for `stderr` to tell where that symbol is.

Comment: in fact what i do not understand is how IDA pro knows this item in .bss is stdout or stderr...

Comment: Okay but what happens if symbol table is stripped ?